# Average and count with conditions - mysql

Tags: mysql, sql, phpmyadmin

table name is data.

Columns - 'date', 'location, 'fp, 'TV'

Under date I will have multiple different dates but each date has a number of rows with the same date. Same with location.

I am trying to work out the average of TV for every time the date and location are the same and fp = 1, and insert the result into a new column called avgdiff

So I might have a number of rows with the date 2016-12-08 and location LA, with different numbers under fp and TV. So when the date is 2016-12-08 and location is LA, fp might equal 1, 4 times, and TV for those 4 rows might be 7.4, 8.2, 1, -2. So the avg will be 3.65.

I think I need to use avg and count functions with conditions but I am having a lot of trouble with this. I hope this makes sense.

Thanks

Comment: It's usually a bad idea to new column for data that can be computed on the fly. It definitely doesn't make sense to store aggregate data in the same table.

Comment: please provide a better example

Comment: `data` is a completely meaningless table name.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can query for the average using a `GROUP BY`:

```
SELECT `date`, `location`, AVG(`TV`) AS `avgtv`
  FROM `data`
 WHERE `fp` = 1
 GROUP BY `date`, `location`
```

To update another table with your computed averages (which I strongly recommend against), you can use an `UPDATE...JOIN` with the above as a subquery:

```
UPDATE ratings r
  JOIN ( /* paste above query here */ ) t
    ON t.date = r.date AND t.location = r.location
   SET r.avgtv = t.avgtv
```

Comment: Thanks, that does work. But the reason why I want to store that data in the table is so I can use that answer in a another query. Obviously that is not the best way but I have just started to learn this, and that's made things easier so far

Comment: @accord You can still use it in another query. Storing it in another column in the same table would mean you would have to duplicate the average for each row in a group. That's a terrible table design.

Comment: Yes there is no reason for me to store in the same table. I have created another table called 'ratings', and made a column avgtv. How would I go about storing the above query in the ratings table?

Comment: Getting this error message #1054 - Unknown column 't.avgtv' in 'field list'

Comment: @accord Sorry, fixed.

Comment: Unfortunately that not working for me either #1052 - Column 'avgtv' in field list is ambiguous

Comment: @accord Fixed again.

Comment: If you strongly recommend against doing the above, what way would you recommend?

Comment: @accord You can query the averages any time you need it, as per the queries above. Storing it accomplishes nothing and is very likely to result in data discrepancies down the road.

Comment: Getting this now - #1054 - Unknown column 'r.date' in 'on clause'

Comment: @accord I assumed your `ratings` table has a `date` and `location` column. I don't know how you're expecting this to work otherwise.

Comment: The reason why I thought I needed to store the averages is because the next thing I want to do is subtract those averages to another query I stored in the table

Comment: Yes I did have them in there, but nothing happened when I updated. That’s probably because there is no data in there right? Sorry very new to all of this, I probably should do some more research before continuing

Comment: @accord You said that about the query already. I told you you don't need an extra column for that. I'm still not sure what your `ratings` table structure looks like. If the columns are there but "nothing happened", that's very different from the error you reported. Yes, you would need to have the rows there in advance, unless you want to do an `INSERT...SELECT...ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE`. But I don't have time to demonstrate that right now.

Comment: Yes I get 0 rows effected, so I need to insert the rows. Will try and look that up, but everything you suggested worked so thanks for your help anwyay

Answer (score 0):

If, for any reason, you cannot avoid storing aggregated data in the same table (thereby introducing redundancy and possibly incorrect/not up to date values),  do an update statement of the following form:

```
update data,
  (select t2.location, t2.date, avg(t2.TV) as avgTV2
   from data t2 
   where t2.fp = 1
   group by t2.location, t2.date) aggValues
set avgTV = avgTV2
where data.location = aggValues.location 
  and data.date = aggValues.date
  and data.fp = 1
```

Comment: Thanks for your response. This does work as well, but like you and shmosel said, there is no reason for me to store in the same table. So have to start learn to store the queries in another table